# Strange Behaviour of Table Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am just implementing a table view in my app. I have done this multiple times but this time the table cell shows the repeating data and speed of table scrolling is not good also. Just posting my code for table. Any help to prevent cell data repetition and scroll speed 
 optimisation will be appreciated.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    int count = [array count];

    if (count%3 == 0)
    {
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        count = count/3+1;
    }
    NSLog(@"Row count is%i",count);
    return count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 490, 221)];
    int x = 15;
    int y = 15;
    int p = 10;
    int q = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if ( indexPath.row*3+i < [array count] )
        {
            UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            [img setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*3+i]]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"India.png"]
                         success:^(UIImage *image) {}failure:^(NSError *error){}];
            img.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 201);
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(p, q, 150, 211);
            btn.tag = indexPath.row*3+i;

            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Picframe_N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Picframe_S.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Movie_detail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [testView addSubview:img];
            [testView addSubview:btn];

            x = x+160;
            p = p+160;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No data");
            break;
        }
    }
    [cell addSubview:testView];
    return cell;
}
```

The Things updated in cell is for the purpose to add 3 buttons in single cell. Nothing else.

Comment: You should use Custom Cell instead.

Comment: @Vin till now i have not approaches towards custom cell. But if the problem will not solve i will approach in that way too..

Answer (score 2):

**SUGGESTION**

Use custom cell

**Fix** :

Creating and adding the subview is to be included inside the braces where the cell is allocated

ie

```
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
         //CREATING AND ADDING SUBVIEW SHOULD BE HERE
    }
          //Change in values is taken care here
```

**REASON**

Otherwise every time a subview is created,allocated all objects and added above when table is scrolled

**REFER**

[Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: Not helpful. It repetes the data every time in cells when i scroll the table view..

Comment: Override the method 'prepareForReuse' in your custom sub-class?

Comment: @singhSan : Well it repeats because you did the change in values in the if loop not else.See if the value needs to change put it only in the else loop

Comment: You setup value to the image .a different image in each cell right .so this is a value which changes ,hence do it in the else case,just the setting up of image creation alloc and all happens in the if loop

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you add a UIView to every cell that comes into the screen. However you are reusing the cells so the old 'added' views are still on them. The repetition of the data is because there are multiple layers of testviews on a cell when you scroll.

You should either make a CustomCell that includes the testview that you are adding at every cellforrow: OR add the testview to the cellviews when the cell is still a nil-value so that if it gets reused you won't add yet another testview to the cell and they overlap. The examples of those are written in other answers here but are found on the web everywhere.

*Not recommended but:
Another quick but dirty fix is to just remove all subviews from the cell (or any subview that you add the testview to) `for(UIView *v in [cell(.contentView) subviews]){ [v removeFromSuperView]; }`*

Comment: Where i should apply this ?

Comment: The dirty fix you should apply BEFORE the first addsubview: in your cellforrow:

Comment: It's adds blank cells in table without data. So not useful.

Comment: That means you either have put the fix too late, or it means you should set the testview (and thus this solutions cell.subview) to another subview. try adding your testview to the contentview or backgroundview of the cell and then remove them with cell.contentview or cell.backgroundview.

Comment: I have already added them at cell.contentview . And one more thing i am adding this line in else method where no data is found in cell. Is this helpful ?

Comment: yes. if no data has been found your testview is empty and thus your cell is empty. If you handle the else case for no data properly you can add ur custom stuff there. It's not strange behaviour anymore tho. now it's how you wanna handle the cases where no data was found. Try adding a backgroundcolor to the testview there and you will notice the change, and the fact that your cell is not empty but just different.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 490, 221)];
    int x = 15;
    int y = 15;
    int p = 10;
    int q = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if ( indexPath.row*3+i < [array count] )
        {
            UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            [img setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*3+i]]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"India.png"]
                         success:^(UIImage *image) {}failure:^(NSError *error){}];
            img.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 201);
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(p, q, 150, 211);
            btn.tag = indexPath.row*3+i;

            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Picframe_N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Picframe_S.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Movie_detail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [testView addSubview:img];
            [testView addSubview:btn];

            x = x+160;
            p = p+160;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No data");
            break;
        }
    }
    [cell addSubview:testView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

You should not initialize anything outside the block where your `cell` is initialized, because when you `scroll` your `tableview` the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` get called everytime, and your view `testview` is getting created everytime..

Outside the cell initialization you should only update the values to be shown in the cell..

Hope above works..

**Edited**
But better approach I would suggest try to create a `Custom Cell` so that you can easily access the components added to your cell to update their values as your tableview scrolls..

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, This returns data repetition in cells on scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

hello this problem is normal when you are using `dequeueReusableCell`

just make change as i listed below in following methode..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    UIView *testView;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 490, 221)];
        testView.tag = 111;
        [cell addSubview:testView];
        [testView release];//For Non ARC
    }
    else
    {
        testView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:111];
        for(UIView * vv in [testView subViews])
        {
            [vv removeFromSuperView];
        }
    }
    int x = 15;
    int y = 15;
    int p = 10;
    int q = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if ( indexPath.row*3+i < [array count] )
        {
            UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            [img setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*3+i]]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"India.png"]
                         success:^(UIImage *image) {}failure:^(NSError *error){}];
            img.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 201);
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(p, q, 150, 211);
            btn.tag = indexPath.row*3+i;

            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Picframe_N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Picframe_S.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Movie_detail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [testView addSubview:img];
            [testView addSubview:btn];

            x = x+160;
            p = p+160;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No data");
            break;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

TRY THIS....

Comment: Hi This approach creates a lot of blank cells in table view. So not helpful.

Comment: have you assigned tags properly?

Comment: try having different cellIdentifiers for different cell view types, for cells that have UIImageView, UIButton you can have different CellIdentifier and for others it should be different

Comment: Yes when i am initialising the UIView at the same time i am assigning tags.. Like you have suggested.

Comment: have you used `[cell.contentView addSubview:testView];`

Comment: @Firdous Can not do that because may be my table view contains some thousand data. So it will be impossible to assign such different identifier to cells..

Comment: When i scrolls the table, it shows me repeated data in cells.

Comment: this might be because you are fetching image from URL every time i suggest you to use [AsynchImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) for testing just take an array of static images from your bundle and try..

Comment: Nirav, i have tried single image in single cell from url and that was working fine. But when i tried to add three images it shows me repeated data in cell on scroll.

Comment: Also the images contains the Lazy loading process to get the images from url.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28788/discussion-between-nirav-gadhiya-and-singhsan)

Answer (score 0):

Repeating data in different cells might be due to same "CellIdentifier", try having different "CellIdentifier" for different cell view types. I can see different cell view types since you are having some condition block in your code.

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier;

MyIdentifier = @"Type1";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }


MyIdentifier = @"Type2";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }
```

Comment: Can not go with this approach.. It's impossible to add so much identifier for each cell.

Comment: not so much, just have differnt one for the simple cell and different one for the one which has UIImageView etc.. just two types

Comment: My all cells contains the images view from the starting. So in this scenario what will be the solution ?

Comment: you can construct your cellIdentifier name dynamically by concatenation, that what is done usually.. but first make sure that this is only the issue, try hardcoding some cells and test if this is the issue

Comment: like this: MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier+%@", someTagValue];